# Convert month name to number in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, date-parsing

Is there some built-in Delphi (XE2)/Windows method to convert month names to numbers 1-12; instead of looping through `(TFormatSettings.)LongMonthNames[]` myself?

Comment: I'm quite sure there's no standard function for this...

Answer (score 7):

You can use `IndexStr` from `StrUtils`, returns `-1` if string not found  e.g.

```
Caption := IntToStr(
  IndexStr(FormatSettings.LongMonthNames[7], FormatSettings.LongMonthNames) + 1);
```

EDIT:
To avoid problems with casting and case sensitivity you might use `IndexText` as shown:

```
Function GetMonthNumber(Const Month:String):Integer; overload;
begin
   Result := IndexText(Month,FormatSettings.LongMonthNames)+1
end;
```

Comment: (Or ANSIText for case insensitivity). I'm not going this way because I then have to cast String<->ANSIString and my code becomes quite unreadable with all the parentheses ;-) I will award this answer points but not mark it as 'the' correct answer. And thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

i can't find a method but i write one. ;-)

```
function GetMonthNumberofName(AMonth: String): Integer;
var
  intLoop: Integer;
begin
  Result:= -1;
  if (not AMonth.IsEmpty) then
  begin
    for intLoop := Low(System.SysUtils.FormatSettings.LongMonthNames) to High(System.SysUtils.FormatSettings.LongMonthNames) do
    begin
      //if System.SysUtils.FormatSettings.LongMonthNames[intLoop]=AMonth then  --> see comment about Case insensitive
      if SameText(System.SysUtils.FormatSettings.LongMonthNames[intLoop], AMonth) then
      begin
        Result:= Intloop;
        Exit
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Ok, I change this function for other FormatSettings.

```
function GetMonthNumberofName(AMonth: String): Integer; overload;
function GetMonthNumberofName(AMonth: String; AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings): Integer; overload;

function GetMonthNumberofName(AMonth: String): Integer;
begin
  Result:= GetMonthNumberofName(AMonth, System.SysUtils.FormatSettings);
end;

function GetMonthNumberofName(AMonth: String; AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings): Integer;
var
  intLoop: Integer;
begin
  Result:= -1;
  if (not AMonth.IsEmpty) then
  begin
    for intLoop := Low(AFormatSettings.LongMonthNames) to High(AFormatSettings.LongMonthNames) do
    begin
      if SameText(AFormatSettings.LongMonthNames[intLoop], AMonth) then
      begin
        Result:= Intloop;
        Exit
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Call the function with the system formatsetting

```
GetMonthNumberofName('may');
```

or with FormatSetting

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iMonth: Integer;
  oSettings:TFormatSettings;
begin
  // Ned
  // oSettings:= TFormatSettings.Create(2067);
  // Fr
  // oSettings:= TFormatSettings.Create(1036);
  // Eng
  oSettings:= TFormatSettings.Create(2057);
  iMonth:= GetMonthNumberofName(self.Edit1.Text, oSettings);
  showmessage(IntToStr(iMonth));
end;
```

Comment: I probably would do a case insensitive comparison, using SameText rather than "=". Also, what about an overloaded version of this function that takes a TFormatSettings parameter?

Comment: @dummzeuch: I don't understand about overloaded the function?

Comment: function GetMonthNumberofName(AMonth: String): Integer; overload; <crlf> function GetMonthNumberofName(AMonth: String; AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings): Integer; overload; <crlf> The second variant uses the given AFormatSettings parameter instead of System.SysUtils.FormatSettings to cater for the case that a program needs to do the conversion for a different locale than the one configured in the operating system. (Sorry for the <crlf>, comments don't allow for line breaks.)