# How to convert month number to month name in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-12-athens

I found a question asking ["Convert month name to number in Delphi?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13701100/22824066).

What's the easiest/best way to do the opposite of that?

I want to get the month name from the month number. Is there a built-in function for this in Delphi?

I want something like a function where I can pass in the month number and get back the name for the month or perhaps even a function where I pass in a `TDate` and get back the month name for that `TDate`.

Is there something like this in Delphi Programming?

I know I can do a bunch of if statements and return the literal string for each month number, but is that really the best/easiest way?

---

For my use case, I only need it to be in English and the full month name.

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in function.  But a bunch of `if` statements would be the last way I'd do it.  Two better ways are an array of names where the month number is the index to the array, or a case statement returning the name for the number.  Another option is an enumerated type where the names of the values can be returned as strings (I don't recall the process off the top of my head).

Comment: Check out the https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime with `mmm`

Comment: There's lots of complexity in this. Have you considered different languages? Do you want to accept abbreviations or only full names, or both. What precisely is your specification?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've updated my question to show my specifications

Comment: That can be easily done by yourself - where's the effort you put into solving this so far? Yes, there is "_something like this_", but it depends under which locale your program is run: executing it on a German Windows installation won't produce English month names (and vice versa).

Comment: Oh wait, I thought you wanted to go from name to month number. But you want to go the other way. Get a [`TFormatSettings`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings) and read from the `LongMonthNames` array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple program to demonstrate one way to do what you want:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  FormatSettings_en_us: TFormatSettings;

procedure Main;
var
  MonthIndex: Integer;
begin
  for MonthIndex := 1 to 12 do begin
    Writeln(FormatSettings_en_us.LongMonthNames[MonthIndex]);
  end;
end;

begin
  FormatSettings_en_us := TFormatSettings.Create('en-us');
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

I've specified US English locale because that's what you asked for in the question. But of course you could use different locales, or not specify a locale in which case the user's locale would be used.

Comment: A minor point, but where did he say that he wanted *US* English?

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment if he wants something different then he can code it differently. Out of interest, is there any variation in the spelling of month names between different forms of English?

Comment: No variations that I'm aware of, and no disagreement with your code; just your comment that he asked for US English.